# Automatic invites to your github organisation

Tags: github, github-organizations

At the moment for a Github organisation of mine, potential members have to be manually searched for an added. Is there way a to make your Github Organization public, so people can easily and automagically join your cause?

I am a beginner with Github, but have searched a lot and they don't seem to have this feature. Is it a plugin anywhere?

---

I see 2 problems, either of which would be nice to fix.

- Why can't users request an invite to your organisation, even if you have to manually approve?
- Why can't I send out bulk invites to say an email list? Or can I do this?

Thanks Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why Github doesn't offer anything like this functionality. Github Organisations seem still kind of underdone, and I look forward to them making them more useful. For the moment I have something which can help you with one of your problems.

---

### Second Problem: Bulk Invites

After needing bulk invite students for a university club I am a part of, I created [thundergolfer/automated-github-organisation-invites](https://github.com/thundergolfer/automated-github-organization-invites). It's a Heroku deploy-able web app that allows anyone with access to the URL to get themselves an organisation invite automatically.

It uses the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-a-member) to do basically what you need. You can send out a bulk email with a link to the web app. Job Done.

### First Problem: Users requesting invites

The problem with the above solution is that you don't get a chance to review who requests an invite. *They are automatically added*. Perhaps when I get time in the future I can extend the project above to allow you to capture requests and then review them before sending out the email.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is the first problem more hard to implement than second?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the first point. But the second point should be no problem. You can use the GitHub API to invite members to your organisation. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-a-member

Answer (score 0):

If using [GitHub classroom](https://classroom.github.com/) then you can solve both problems. In the classroom you can add multiple email invites at the same time (or link with a LMS to get the list of people to invite automatically, both are explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTzrKduaHj8&list=PLIRjfNq867bewk3ZGV6Z7a16YDNRCpK3u&index=2)). You can also create an assignment and end up with a link that can be sent to people to join. Within an assignment there can be auto Team and Repo creation.

With your second problem another option is a python script that can bulk invite users to a GitHub organisation:
https://github.com/RobbyJ/github_batch_organisation_invite